# Error filtering multiple csv files based on rows

Tags: python, data-cleaning, keyerror

I have a folder that contains 20 csv files. Each file has about 10 columns and thousands of rows. The csv files look something like the following:

| gene | p-value | xyz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| acan | 0.05 | 123 |
| mmp2 | 0.02 | 456 |
| mmp9 | 0.07 | 789 |
| nnos | 0.09 | 123 |
| gfap | 0.01 | 456 |

I have written the following script with the purpose of going through each file and filtering the rows only by the genes of interest that I have indicated (in this case mmp2 and mmp9) and then saving the csv file only with those rows.

```
# the goal is to edit and save the csv files so they only contain the genes of interest

path = '/Users/adriana/Library/Documents/raw_data'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv")) #make list of file paths 
genes = ["mmp2", "mmp9"]
for file in all_files:
    path = '/Users/adriana/Library/Documents/raw_data'
    df = pd.read_csv(file,delimiter ='\t')
    cleaned = df[df['gene'].isin(genes)]
    cleaned.to_csv(file)
```

However, I get the following error:

KeyError: 'gene'

Not sure why I am getting this error as this is a column in each of my files.

Comment: maybe add a `print(file)` within your loop to see which file is doing this

Comment: most probably, one of your csv does not include gene columns or have a blank before its name like ' gene' instead of 'gene'. also, there is no need to have path variable in for loop.

Comment: If we assume that one or more of the data files lack a column case sensitively named "gene", what would you like to do?  Skip that file? Try again with some alternate column name as a fallback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try skipping the dfs that it says are missing a `gene` column. And check to see if the column names exactly match the word `gene` by printing `df.info()`. This way the code won't fail and you can see which dfs are causing the issue

```py
if 'gene' in df.columns:
    cleaned = df[df['gene'].isin(genes)]
    ...
else:
    print(df.info())
```